# Swift, iOS: How to detect GCController button being held when only given a pressedChangedHandler?

Tags: swift, button, controller

My solution is hacky and frankly doesn't even work because the spin loop halts other simultaneous button actions from being recognized. I'd love to be able to use a long press gesture recognizer, but that 's not available on GCController.

```
    let dPadLeftButtonPressedChangedHandler = {
        (dPadLeftButton: GCControllerButtonInput, value: Float, pressed: Bool) -> Void in
        
        if dPadLeftButton.isPressed {
            // No longer nil
            self.moveLeft()
            self.nanoTimer = DispatchTime.now()

            while (dPadLeftButton.isPressed) {
                let nanoTimerNow = DispatchTime.now()

                // Thousandths of a second
                let timeDifference = (nanoTimerNow.uptimeNanoseconds - self.nanoTimer!.uptimeNanoseconds) / UInt64(1000000)

                // 200 / 1000 is .2 seconds
                if timeDifference > 250 {
                    self.hardLeft()
                    self.nanoTimer = nil
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }


    controller?.extendedGamepad?.dpad.left.pressedChangedHandler = dPadLeftButtonPressedChangedHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by initialzing a CADisplayLink object to call the function I want repeated via the selector argument. Then on the button release, I invalidate the CADisplayLink.